# Wp all import: Updated existing Posts and check if acf value is matching csv value

Tags: php, wordpress, import, advanced-custom-fields, wpallimport

I'm stuck with my custom csv import.

I have a CPT 'Artists' with over 1000 entries. Each CPT has a acf field 'kuenummber' with a uniq number. It's already stored in the wp database. Now I have csv file with the same number and I would like to import some fields if the csv number is matching the acf field 'kuekummber'.

Any help is welcome. Sorry for my english. All the best, Carol

Comment: Any approach you have tried till now?.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.